# Footable or Datatables with 10000 rows

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

I need to show the table with 15 columns, wich have about 10000 rows. When I load simply table without Limit, It loads too slow. Because at first there shows all rows, and after that Datatable hides rows. Maybe there are some solutions for this case?

But I need that it shows all pages count for example:

| < Previous | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | ... | **690** | Next > |

Now I'm using simple `foreach ($res as $r){ echo "<tr><td>$r->id</td></tr>"; }`

In addition, I would like to add that I have in first column script for popup like:

`echo <td><a href="#" onClick="popitup(http://example.com/?id=2)">'.$rowid.'</a></td>;`

Answer (score 0):

If you work with Datatables with large data like in your case you need to load data like this

https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html

and you can also add this option

https://datatables.net/reference/option/deferRender

Answer (score 0):

When returning this amount of rows you should probably be using the Ajax functionality of datatables. More info can be found here:

https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html